# Dom elements do not work with 1 variable and do not work with "let" variables

Tags: javascript

✅ **Works when creating 2 variables:**

```js
var val;

var list = document.querySelector('.list-group');

val = list;


val = list.childNodes;

console.log(val);
```

```html
    <ul class="list-group">
        <li>1</li>
        <li>2</li>
    </ul>
```

❌ **1 variable does not work:**

```js
var list = document.querySelector('.list-group');


list.childNodes;

console.log(val);
```

```html
     <ul class="list-group">
        <li>1</li>
        <li>2</li>
    </ul>
```

❌ **Doesn't work in firefox and chrome console with let variable:**

```js
let val;

let list = document.querySelector('.list-group');

val = list;


val = list.childNodes;

console.log(val);
```

```html
    <ul class="list-group">
        <li>1</li>
        <li>2</li>
    </ul>
```

[image]

**works with the same operations on Udemy video and StackOverflow**

[image]

### **What are the differences between? Why firefox does not work with the let variable?**

Comment: Your second snippet doesn't work because you've never declared a variable named `val`. If you wanted a single variable with the `childNodes`, then do `document.querySelector('.list-group').childNodes`

Comment: Your second piece of code does nothing because you `console.log(val)` but you never assigned it. Try `console.log(list)`. Your third piece of code works fine on firefox; your issue is that you have already declared `val` and so can't redeclare it